# Pseudoelemento 'after' no se ve

Tags: css3

tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
<div style="background:green">
     <ul class="list-unstyled multi-steps">
        <li>Start</li>
        <li>First Step</li>
        <li class="is-active">Middle Stage</li>
        <li>Finish</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
        .multi-steps > li.is-active:before, .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:before {
  content: counter(stepNum);
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active:after, .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:after {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.multi-steps {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.multi-steps > li {
  counter-increment: stepNum;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  color: tomato;
}
.multi-steps > li:before {
  content: '\f00c';
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.multi-steps > li:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.multi-steps > li:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: tomato;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li {
  color: #808080;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:before {
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-color: #ededed;
}
```

El contenido de 'after' no se visualiza, pero al quitarle el bakground al contenedo, si se ve.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el valor de tu `z-index` a 1 el -1 hará que quede debajo.

```css
multi-steps > li.is-active:before, .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:before {
  content: counter(stepNum);
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active:after, .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:after {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.multi-steps {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.multi-steps > li {
  counter-increment: stepNum;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  color: tomato;
}
.multi-steps > li:before {
  content: '\f00c';
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.multi-steps > li:after {
 content: '';
 height: 2px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: tomato;
 position: absolute;
 top: 16px;
 left: 50%;
 z-index: 1;
}
.multi-steps > li:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: tomato;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li {
  color: #808080;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:before {
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-color: #ededed;
}
.multi-steps > li:before { position: relative; z-index: 2}
```

```html
<div style="background:green;">
 <ul id="list" class="list-unstyled multi-steps">
  <li>Start</li>
  <li>First Step</li>
  <li class="is-active">Middle Stage</li>
  <li>Finish</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Eso hice pero el resultado no es el deseado. Actualizé con todo el CSS para que veas.:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JWr3jFLzRZD6FLkyOHdiraus3LVRDE5d/view?usp=sharing

Así es como se ve.

Comment: que tendrá content? el  check?

Comment: Sumá `.multi-steps > li:before { position: relative; z-index: 2}`.

Comment: No, content contiene la linea divisoria entre los circulos.

Comment: Graciaaaaaassss! Eres grande con CSS.

Comment: @RaymondMedina si esta respuesta solucionó el problema. Por favor, márcala como aceptada.